# How to apply the parameters of view to all the directories?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I know how to setup the mode of the view for a directory: sorting, the size of icons, etc... However, this gets applied only to the current directory. Whereas I want to apply them to all the directories. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you're in a directory press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to see the View options.

Now go about setting the view options exactly how you'd like them to be. Once completed, click on the <kbd>Use as Defaults</kbd> button at bottom centre of the View options window. This will set your configuration as the default for all directories.

Comment: that won't get applied for *all* the directories that exist on my Mac -- some directories are still displayed using other options